# Reverse an ostringstream by line

Tags: c++, ostringstream

```
ostringstream ss;
ss << "(1,2)\n" << "(1,3)\n" << "(1,4)\n" ;
cout << ss.str();
```

should print the following:

> (1,2)
>
> (1,3)
>
> (1,4)

How could i reverse the output by line so that it prints:

> (1,4)
>
> (1,3)
>
> (1,2)

Comment: Read/extract one line at a time, and store it in a vector, then print each element of the vector in the reverse order.

Comment: can't do that...this is just a snippet of my code simplified

Comment: There is no EASY way to do that - reading a line at a time is the way to do it - you can either use a stack and print the order they came in, or store in a vector and print using a reverse iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your original code **with C++98**:

```
  ostringstream ss;
  ss << "(1,2)\n" << "(1,3)\n" << "(1,4)\n" ;
  cout << ss.str();

  //assign a string to the contents of the ostringstream:
  string rawlines = ss.str();

  //now create an input stringstream with the value of the rawlines
  istringstream iss(rawlines);

  string temp;//just a temporary object used for storage
  vector<string> lines;//this is where your lines will be held

  //now iterate over the stream and store the contents into the vector `lines`:
  while(getline(iss, temp)) {
      lines.push_back(temp);
  }

  //now reverse the contents:
  reverse(lines.begin(), lines.end());

  //see what's inside:
  for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
  }
```

This will print:

```
(1,4)
(1,3) 
(1,2)
```

As desired

NOTE: **This strips the newlines from the the original string.**
And, this requires:

```
//for `getline`:
#include <cstdlib>
//for `reverse`:
#include <algorithm>
//for `string`:
#include <string>
//for `vector`:
#include <vector>
```

Comment: just change from push_back to push_front and used a dequeue instead

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom `std::streambuf` which internally keeps a stack of `std::string`s and puts them together upon using a `str()` member. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class stackbuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
    std::vector<std::string> d_lines;
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            this->d_lines.back().push_back(c);
            if (c == '\n') {
                this->d_lines.push_back(std::string());
            }
        }
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
public:
    stackbuf(): d_lines(1) {}
    std::string str() const {
        return std::accumulate(this->d_lines.rbegin(),
                               this->d_lines.rend(),
                               std::string());
    }
};

int main()
{
    stackbuf sbuf;
    std::ostream out(&sbuf);
    out << "(1, 2)\n(1, 3)\n(1, 4)\n";
    std::cout << sbuf.str();
}
```

For a real-world application you should, obviously, set up a buffer in the stream buffer to improve the performance. You may also want to create a custom stream directly initializing the stream's stream buffer.

Comment: Excellent solution. Great example of the `std::streambuf` usage and by far the best way to reuse the requested algorithm in your code. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse iterators:

> ```
> std::ostringstream ss{ "(1,2)\n(1,3)\n(1,4)\n" };
> std::string str = ss.str();
>
> std::copy( str.rbegin(), str.rend(),
>            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, "\n"} );
> ```

This code will require:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <iterator>
> #include <string>
> #include <sstream>
> ```

and basic C++11 support.

Comment: I don't understand why other answers have 20k lines of freakness code, for a thing that could be easily achieved through this four beautiful and clear sentences

Comment: Late reply but this doesn't work. The input_iterators iterate through chars while the ostream_iterator iterate through strings.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the classic way, best leveraging the standard C++ library.

```
#include <iostream>                                                      
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char* arv[])
{
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << "(1,2)\n" << "(1,3)\n" << "(1,4)\n" ;
  cout << oss.str() << "----------\n";
  // Reverse lines
  // Fill an istringstream with buffer contents of the ostringstream
  istringstream iss(oss.str());
  stack<string> stk;
  while (iss) {
    string s;
    if (!getline(iss, s)) break; // Read a line
    s += '\n';                   // Put back newline stripped by readline
    stk.push(s);                 // Push line to stack
  }
  oss.clear();                   // Clear state of the ostringstream
  oss.str("");                   // Clear contents of the ostringstream for reuse
  while (!stk.empty()) {
    string s;
    s = stk.top();               // Get top of stack
    oss << s;                    // Output it to the ostringstream
    stk.pop();                   // Pop and throw away top of stack
  }
  cout << oss.str();
  return 0;
}
```